# What is scikit-learn's LogisticRegression minimizing?

Tags: logistic, maximum-likelihood, scikit-learn

I have used `linear_model.LogisticRegression` for a classification problem, with L1 regularization. My first tests were very satisfactory. However, my previous tests were done in R, using the glmnet package, and now I would like to understand why they differ.

I am trying to derive manually (by hand) the objective function minimized by `linear_model.LogisticRegression`. According to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression), the function is $||w||_1 + C \sum_i \log(\exp(-y_i (X_i^T w + c)) + 1)$. However, I am failing to obtain this equation.

The starting point of my derivation is the negative log-likelihood, which I can work down into three derivations.

One derivation follows Andrew Ng's approach, which minimizes a function like $\sum y \log (p(x)) + (1-y_i) \log(1-p(x))$ (note that here $y\in\{0,1\}$). The second approach follows closely this lecture (http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/uADA/12/lectures/ch12.pdf , section 12.2.1), which results in a similar equation to the one used by scikit-learn, but not quite the same: $-\sum_i \log(1 + \exp(X_i^Tw+c)) + \sum_i y_i(X_i^Tw+c) + (\text{L1 term})$ (adapted to scikit-learn notation from equation 12.10). Close, but not cigar!

The third approach follows http://people.csail.mit.edu/jrennie/writing/lr.pdf, where $y\in\{1,-1\}$, like scikit-learn (internally), where the objective function is $-\sum_i \log(y_i g(X_i^Tw + c)) + (\text{L1 term})$, where $g(z) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-z}}$ is the logistic function (adapted from equation 7). Here, the objective function resembles scikit-learn's function, but the exponential term is inverted and the $y$ is not inside the exponential.

**So the question is**: what exactly is the L1 regularized logistic regression of scikit-learn minimizing ?

If it really is the likelihood, then my derivation is probably wrong at some point, is there a reference that explains the equation minimized according to the docs (and according to `sklearn/svm/src/liblinear/linear.cpp`) ?

If it's not the likelihood, what is it, and where can I find more information?

Comment: Actually, I re-did my derivation, and found the exact same equation that scikit uses. I'll post the derivation in a minute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nevermind my question, I did the derivation once again and found out that the scikit equation is correct, and it is minimizing the negative log likelihood.
Here are the steps:

Let $(X_i,y_i), i=1,\dots,m$ be pairs of (features, class), where $X_i$ is a column-vector of $N$ features. The class $y_i\in\{1,-1\}$ will be limited to these two values (instead of 0 and 1), which will be useful later.

We are trying to model the probability of a $X$ feature vector to be of class $y=1$ as:
$$p(y=1|X;w,c) = g(X_i^Tw+c) = \frac{1}{1+\exp(-(X_i^Tw+c))}\,,$$
where $w,c$ are the weights and intercept of the logistic regression model.

To obtain the optimal $w,c$, we want to maximize the likelihood given the database of labeled data. The optimization problem is:
$$\begin{align} \mathop{argmax}_\theta\quad& \mathcal{L}(w,c;X_1,\dots,X_m) \\
&= \prod_{i,y_i=1} p(y=1|X_i;w,c) \prod_{i,y_i=-1} p(y=-1|X_i;w,c) \\
&\langle \text{There are only two classes, so } p(y=-1|\dots) = 1-p(y=1|\dots)\rangle\\
&= \prod_{i,y_i=1} p(y=1|X_i;w,c) \prod_{i,y_i=-1} (1-p(y=1|X_i;w,c)) \\
&\langle \text{Definition of } p\rangle\\
&= \prod_{i,y_i=1} g(X_i^Tw +c) \prod_{i,y_i=-1} (1-g(X_i^Tw +c)) \\
&\langle \text{Useful property: } 1-g(z) = g(-z) \rangle\\
&= \prod_{i,y_i=1} g(X_i^Tw +c) \prod_{i,y_i=-1} g(-(X_i^Tw +c)) \\
&\langle \text{Handy trick of using +1/-1 classes: multiply by } y_i \text{ to have a common product}\rangle\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^m g(y_i (X_i^Tw +c)) \\
\end{align}$$

At this point I decided to apply the logarithm function (since its monotonically increasing) and flip the maximization problem to a minimization, by multiplying by -1:

$$\begin{align}
\mathop{argmin}_\theta\quad & -\log \left(\prod_{i=1}^m g(y_i (X_i^Tw +c))\right) \\
&\langle \log (a\cdot b) = \log a + \log b \rangle\\
&= -\sum_{i=1}^{m} \log g(y_i (X_i^Tw +c)) \\
&\langle \text{definition of } g \rangle\\
&= -\sum_{i=1}^{m} \log \frac{1}{1+\exp(-y_i (X_i^Tw +c))} \\
&\langle \log (a/b) = \log a - \log b \rangle\\
&= -\sum_{i=1}^{m} \log 1 - \log (1+\exp(-y_i (X_i^Tw +c))) \\
&\langle \log 1 \text{ is a constant, so it can be ignored} \rangle\\
&= -\sum_{i=1}^{m} - \log (1+\exp(-y_i (X_i^Tw +c))) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{m} \log (\exp(-y_i (X_i^Tw +c))+1)\,,
\end{align}$$
which is exactly the equation minimized by scikit-learn (without the L1 regularization term, and with $C=1$)

Comment: Really nice explanation. The documentation should provide more mathematical information just like you did here.